# How to login with corporate account when using Microsoft Account identity provider in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, authorization, azure-ad-b2c

I want to build an application where users can log in with their corporate Microsoft / Azure AD account.

For that, I created a Azure AD B2C incl. SignUpSignIn user flow with the "Microsoft Account" identity provider.

Now when I want to log in I get redirected to https://login.live.com/ and can successfully log in with my personal microsoft account. However, if I enter the email address of my corporate account, the error message "This microsoft account is not available" comes up.

The `signInAudience` of my app registration is set to `AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount`. So I would expect that also corporate accounts should work?

Answer (score 0):

"Microsoft account" there refers only to personal Microsoft accounts (Outlook/Live/Hotmail accounts).

If you want to only authenticate with one Azure AD tenant, there is guidance for adding that as an identity provider: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow.

Multi-tenant Azure AD authentication could be done with the generic OpenID Connect provider I think: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-generic-openid-connect?pivots=b2c-user-flow

It can also be achieved through custom policies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think the term "Microsoft Account " in combination with the audience "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount" ist a bit misleading then.

Because I need multi-tenant authentication I tried to set it up via OpenId Connect and also with a custom policy as stated in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy.

Neither of these approaches works. Either the GET request to /authorize returns a 400 with response "Bad Request" or I get the error "An exception occured".

Comment: When using the custom policy I get an server error "We encountered an 'invalid_client' error connecting to the identity provider. Please try again later."

Do you have any other documentation or tutorial?

Comment: That documentation page for multi-tenant integration with custom policies is probably what I would have linked :\ Debugging custom policy issues is usually easier if you have Application Insights integrated there.

Comment: Ah I can see in the logs that it indeed used the wrong clientId which I changed earlier. It just took some time until the changes were live. Now the custom policy approach works as expected. Thanks.